# Count SQL with multiple conditions on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that returns the customers who bought 'mirrors' or 'bike' after 01-jan-2020 and within 12 months also bought 'book' or 'sofa' (using count in case they bought more than once). the query i wrote is incomplete so i need some help- I'm missing the column that count the number of orders within the next 12 months.

Here's my data:
[image]

The query i wrote(which is incomplete)

```
select Customer_id, product,order_date,count(o2.order_date)
from Orders o1
left join orders o2
on o1.customer_id=o2.customer_id
and o2.order_date>o1.order_date
where o1.product='mirror' or o1.product='bike' then '1'
and TO_DATE( '1 Jan 2020', 'DD MON YYYY' )
```

I tried left join and CTE but both didn't work since i can't find the right way to use +365 days and another product condition.

Comment: You don't need joins here. The condition seems trivial to put in a where clause

Comment: 1) Please don't use images, use editable text so someone can copy your data to try out a solution 2) Please update your question with the result you expect based on your sample data

Comment: The expected output from the sample data is zero rows as there are no customers who have bought a mirror or a bike and anything else.

Comment: @pavi2410 As the conditions are fulfilled across separate rows, I'd love to see your answer using just a WHERE clause.

Comment: @MatBailie I think it is possible using only analytic functions and `WHERE` filters [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SyJfkNl_). I'm not yet convinced that it covers all edge-cases though.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT o.*
  FROM Orders o
 WHERE o.order_date >= DATE '2020-01-01'
   AND o.order_date <  DATE '2021-01-01'
   AND o.product IN ('mirror', 'bike')
   AND EXISTS (
         SELECT *
           FROM Orders
          WHERE customer_id = o.customer_id
            AND order_date <  o.order_date
            AND order_date >= ADD_MONTHS(o.order_date, -12)
            AND product IN ('book', 'sofa')
       )
```

Stealing the fiddle setup from @MT0 gives the following...

| CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT | ORDER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | mirror | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yFhDS31F)

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Orders
  WHERE  order_date >= DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    order_date <  DATE '2022-01-01'
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER BY order_date
  MEASURES
    COUNT(*) AS num_orders
  PATTERN (book_or_sofa other* mirror_or_bike other*)
  DEFINE
    book_or_sofa   AS  product IN ('book', 'sofa')
                   AND order_date < DATE '2021-01-01',
    mirror_or_bike AS  product IN ('mirror', 'bike')
                   AND order_date <= ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(order_date), 12),
    other          AS  order_date <= ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(order_date), 12)
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Orders (customer_id, product, order_date) AS
  SELECT 'Alice', 'book',   DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Alice', 'mirror', DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Beryl', 'sofa',   DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Beryl', 'other',  DATE '2020-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Beryl', 'mirror', DATE '2021-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Carol', 'mirror', DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Carol', 'sofa',   DATE '2020-02-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | NUM_ORDERS |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 2 |

or, if you want all the matching rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Orders
  WHERE  order_date >= DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    order_date <  DATE '2022-01-01'
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER BY order_date
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (book_or_sofa other* mirror_or_bike other*)
  DEFINE
    book_or_sofa   AS  product IN ('book', 'sofa')
                   AND order_date < DATE '2021-01-01',
    mirror_or_bike AS  product IN ('mirror', 'bike')
                   AND order_date <= ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(order_date), 12),
    other          AS  order_date <= ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(order_date), 12)
);
```

Which outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_DATE | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | book |
| Alice | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | mirror |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BmMvI7R7)

---

If you want a count of the mirrors or bikes in the 12-months since a book or sofa was bought then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Orders
  WHERE  order_date >= DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    order_date <  DATE '2022-01-01'
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER BY order_date
  MEASURES
    COUNT(mirror_or_bike.*) AS num_orders
  PATTERN ( ^ other*? (book_or_sofa (other*? mirror_or_bike)*)? )
  DEFINE
    book_or_sofa   AS  product IN ('book', 'sofa')
                   AND order_date < DATE '2021-01-01',
    mirror_or_bike AS  product IN ('mirror', 'bike')
                   AND order_date < ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(order_date), 12),
    other          AS  order_date < ADD_MONTHS(FIRST(order_date), 12)
);
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER_ID | NUM_ORDERS |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 |
| Beryl | 0 |
| Carol | 0 |
| Debra | 0 |
| Emily | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1yAkdVL1)

Answer (score 0):

This is closer, but it's not clear what you want to have happen when a customer has more than one initial mirror or bike order.

```
SELECT o1.Customer_id, o1.product, o1.order_date, count(o2.order_date) 
FROM Orders o1
INNER JOIN Orders o2
    ON o1.customer_id=o2.customer_id
        AND o2.order_date>=o1.order_date
        AND o2.order_date < ADD_MONTHS(o1.order_date, 12)
        AND o2.product IN ('book', 'sofa')
WHERE o1.product IN ('mirror', 'bike')
```

Comment: This is not valid in Oracle as you get `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`.